# Can I write Unit Test cases and functional level test cases in Groovy?

Tags: eclipse, unit-testing, groovy, automation

I need to create a framework which can support Unit test cases and functional automated test-cases for one of my projects. Can I use groovy for the same instead of using jUnit? If yes, what all are the tools that can be used? How to setup.?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could e. g. use the [Spock Framework](http://spockframework.github.io/spock/docs/1.0/index.html) which is a Groovy based testing framework that also has a JUnit runner and thus is compatible with IDEs, CI-Servers, ...

Comment: Can you give me some notes on how to start if I want to start with using eclipse?

Comment: Nope, sorry. In my eyes Eclipse is crap for Java development compared to IntelliJ IDEA which I use and which is the best Java IDE under the sun. If the documentation and the example project it references is not enough for you, you could also have a look at Gradle which also uses Spock for their testing and acutally invented Spock.

Answer (score 0):

First up you need the `STS` (Eclipse customized by SpringSource) or you may download the STS plugin for the latest version of `Eclipse for Java EE developer`.
You need to decide on which version of groovy you plan to use.
Download the spock version built for that version of groovy.

You may use this [link](https://spring.io/blog/2009/07/30/a-groovier-eclipse-experience) here to work through the steps.